# SvelteKit private assets

Tags: sveltekit

I want to load data in `+page.server.ts` from a file local to my SvelteKit project.

Initially, I tried saving the file in `routes/foo/bar.txt` and loading it into `routes/foo/+page.server.ts` like so:

```js
import fs from "fs";
import url from "url";
import path from "path";

function getData() {
      const dirname = path.dirname(url.filURLToPath(import.meta.url));
      const filePath = path.join(dirname, "bar.txt");
      const data = fs.readFileSync(filePath, "utf8");

      return data;
}
```

However, I end up getting `ENOENT` when trying to load the file, with the error saying that no file exists at `project/build/server/chunks/bar.txt`.
(I am using adapter node.)

I don't want it to be available publicly, so I can't store it in `src/static`.

How can I process this file on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `import` the path to the file that you want to access directly, and [Vite will load the data for you](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#explicit-url-imports):

```js
import filePath from "./bar.txt?url";

function getData() {
      const data = fs.readFileSync(filePath, "utf8");

      return data;
}
```

Alternatively, directly [`import` the file itself](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-string):

```js
import data from './bar.txt?raw'

function getData() {
      return data;
}
```